# COGNOS Report Studio - How to view all tables/columns from a datasource using SQL?

Tags: sql, cognos, cognos-10

I am creating a report on Report Studio, using SQL queries. I add the SQL object to the queries pane and set a data source.

How can I list the datasource's tables (and the table's columns) using SQL queries?

If it helps, the underlying database is Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

List of tables:

```
SELECT DISTINCT table_name FROM all_tables
```

List of columns:

```
SELECT column_name FROM all_tab_columns
```

List of columns for a specific database:

```
SELECT column_name FROM all_tab_columns 
WHERE table_name = UPPER('{table name}')
```

Comment: Did it work? I'm attempting to do the same thing and although my SQL query validates properly, I get a message saying no values available once I run my report, which is definitely surprising...